# What is a word for a good two way communication?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Let's say I had a good conversation with another person. It had a good flow to it and it didn't feel like it was just one sided.

Is there an adjective or an adverb to describe this kind of conversation?

Thanks!

Comment: we had a GOOD talk!

Comment: Mutually beneficial conversation?

Comment: It may not necessarily be mutually beneficial in a sense that both sides got what they wanted. However, it may still be productive by virtue of having a good "flow" to the conversation on both sides.

Comment: Keep it simple: you had an 'enjoyable conversation'.

Comment: Meaningful/ effective communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest bilateral communication. Edit: Or, unilateral communication for the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

a **productive** talk.  [TFD](https://www.freethesaurus.com/productive)

> 2. Marked by abundant production or achievement:
> 3. Yielding favorable or useful results; constructive:

As in:

> We had a very *productive* conversation!

Comment: or "productive intercourse"  .. I swear that was a common term that you would read 40 years ago without it causing snickers

Comment: @Tom22 indeed!!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the opposite of a one-sided conversation is a two-sided conversation, but it’s not very common or idiomatic.

My first thought was [balanced conversation](http://changingminds.org/techniques/conversation/sustaining/balanced_conversation.htm), which does at least appear to be used in several articles, and sounds idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 0):

You already provided the answer in your own question: **a good conversation**.

The very definition of **conversation** (per Merriam-Webster online) is an "oral exchange of sentiments, observations, opinions, or ideas."

Although the phrase "a one-sided conversation" is often used, it doesn't actually make logical sense. A "one-sided conversation" cannot *be* a conversation—as it wouldn't involve an "exchange". Logically, it would be like saying "a silent musical." Instead, it would be more accurate to say that the person attempted to have a conversation but failed.

Idiomatically, however, nobody misunderstands what a "one-sided conversation" means.

So, try a synonym like **dialogue**: "an exchange of ideas and opinions."

Answer (score 0):

You could say "the conversation was **reciprocal**" or that "it was **reciprocated** by the other person" to indicate that they had the same level of involvement and interest in the conversation as yourself.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocate) "reciprocate":

> 1. to give and take mutually
> 2. to return in kind or degree